# Optimum Number of Parallel Processes

Tags: parallelism

I just finished coding a (basic) ray tracer in C# for fun and for the learning experience. Now I want to further that learning experience. It seems to me that ray tracing is a prime candidate for parallel processing, which is something I have very little experience in. My question is this: how do I know the optimum number of concurrent processes to run?

My first instinct tells me: it depends on how many cores my processor has, but like I said I'm new to this and I may be neglecting something.

Comment: "how do I know the optimum number of concurrent processes to run?" - by testing for different numbers. Sometimes an algorithm doesn't gain much from running in parallel (considering the overheads).

Comment: And once you have the number of cores, you can start wondering about the wonderful problems of [Load Balancing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)), if it is [Dynamic Load Balancing](http://www2.cs.uni-paderborn.de/cs/ag-monien/RESEARCH/LOADBAL/) it can be even more fun!

Comment: @Zenon - Ah. I had thought load balancing would be an issue if I was doing distributed computing over several disparate machines, not cores in the same machine.

Comment: @SystemDown - Well, as soon as your computations are not done sequentially, you will have to worry about how to divise the tasks and how to merge them together at the end, also who and when can modify the objects shared between the processes, and how the memory is divided between the processes. The implementation is (IMO) more complicated when you do it with many machines, but the "spirit" stays the same. Some languages are easier to distribute (e.g. [Scala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_(programming_language))) but you will always have to make a lot of decisions.

Comment: The answer depends on how you structure your code and what your target hardware architecture is like.  Programming for GPUs is different from multicore CPUs.  I upvoted Mike Brown's answer because it likely answers your question and is applicable to your existing code, but for an example of other ways to structure your code, read [cache-oblivious algorithms.](http://www.1024cores.net/home/parallel-computing/cache-oblivious-algorithms)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .NET framework has a built-in setting that optimizes the number of concurrent threads if you use the [ThreadPool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool?view=net-6.0) directly or the more convenient [Task Parallel Library](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) API. I believe it is something like 20 per logical core (but I don't see that in the documentation anymore). If you want to control your threads directly, you can still call the ThreadPool's [GetMaxThreads](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.getmaxthreads?view=net-6.0) function to see what the framework recommends. For a really neat demo of leveraging the features of C#, check out this [raytracer implemented using LINQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/lukeh/taking-linq-to-objects-to-extremes-a-fully-linqified-raytracer)

**Updating for new information** According to the current documentation

> Beginning with the .NET Framework 4, the default size of the thread pool for a process depends on several factors, such as the size of the virtual address space. A process can call the GetMaxThreads method to determine the number of threads. The number of threads in the thread pool can be changed by using the SetMaxThreads method. Each thread uses the default stack size and runs at the default priority.

Of course the important thing is to recognize that for a CPU bound operation, theoretically there should be one thread per core. But also recognize that your application (without explicitly setting thread priority) will have to share time on the core with other processes. Meaning, optimal threading depends on a number of factors. By default, I'd let the system manage threading for me. The Task Parallel Library is the best route for that currently.

Comment: Wait. Does that mean that "for each" is automatically parallelized?

Comment: If you use Parallel.ForEach it is.

Comment: 20 Threads per logical core seems a bit exaggerated. To be honest I did some tuning on the JVM  (The JVM thread pool has a little bit more than 1 thread per logical core) and even when I used lightweight Akka threads depending on the application I rarely got an optimum slightly above 2 threads per logical core. The .NET framework might be different, but I doubt it can be so different.

Comment: Hmmm this was some time ago so it's probably changed. Remember when .NET was first released multi-core processors were not around and it was strongly tied to the Windows platform. A .NET thread WAS a thin wrapper around a Windows thread. A .NET threadpool reserves and manages its own group of Windows threads and at the time I answered this, it was the default setting. Might have changed since though.

Comment: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2242307/14359) the default count is 250 per core on the thread pool. But the documentation has since changed. It says the default number is affected by several factors.

Comment: Correction, he's saying that the OS makes 250 threads per available core, within a .NET application I believe it reserves 20 for the threadpool for each core (or used to) from those already allotted by the OS. 

Of course the important thing is to recognize that for a CPU bound operation, IDEALLY there should be one thread per core. But also recognize, that your application (without explicitly setting thread priority) will have to share time on the core with other processes. Meaning, optimal threading depends.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum improvement one could achieve is described by [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law). How parallelizable your application can become is a combination of the task and algorithms used. To determine the optimal number of processor cores will involve measuring performance and probably simulation.

Answer (score 1):

For something like raytracing that is strictly compute bound, and almost infinitely parallelizable you want the same number of threads as (logical) CPU cores, but you might reduce this a bit to leave a bit of resources for other process, the UI and such.

If you know your work can be executed fully in cache, and with large degree of instruction level parallelism, you might want to use physical cores instead of logical cores, since Simultaneous multithreading (SMT) is mostly used to hide memory access latency. So using two threads per physical core might cause contention over the shared cache.

If the work you are doing can block on some type of shared resource (locks, IO, network etc), then it might in some cases be useful with more threads. But ideally non-blocking programming techniques should be used where possible.

If you are parallelizing processes instead of threads you can just use `1 thread = 1 process`

Answer (score 0):

Sound engineering practice would be to test and measure the actual target system if useful values can’t be read from a table.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you don’t want: 1. A powerful computer twiddling its thumbs because you did give it not enough work. 2. A powerful computer becoming sluggish and not reacting to the user because you give it too much work.

Check out what tools you have available. On my OS I can give every thread a priority: From brutally grabbing all resources, to “normal” scheduling with other threads in other apps, to using CPU time until the UI needs time for anything and getting out of the way. That’s likely what you want, a priority level where all cores are used but the user gets preference.

Check out at which point your system starts swapping memory. Using too many threads can slow you down when you run out of RAM. You *may* be able to detect this and stop threads.

And then you just try out what number of threads gives you best performance.